# Why does `array_ndims(array[])` produce NULL?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I'm trying to test for an empty array.  I understand the reasoning behind `array_length` returing `NULL` since it's a 0-dimensional array, but why is `array_ndims(array[]::int array)` not `0`, but rather `NULL`?

Comment: http://www.postgresql-archive.org/array-ndims-never-returns-zero-td5998579.html please accept @Lukasz answer - as it the right one (at least today) and indeed is not documented (at least today) properly

Comment: @VaoTsun, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it will never return 0:

```
/* Sanity check: does it look like an array at all? */
    if (AARR_NDIM(v) <= 0 || AARR_NDIM(v) > MAXDIM)
        PG_RETURN_NULL();
```

You could write your own C function for this, simply change `<= 0` into `< 0`. As for reasoning behind this, I can't find anything.

Source is in: https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/v10.1/  (same thing for 9.6.2, with is what I checked initially)

File: `./src/backend/utils/adt/arrayfuncs.c`

Look for simple, 10 line function: `array_ndims`

Comment: please put a link to codebase. I also would expect to see the number of empty array to be zero. Maybe smbd just wanted to avoid checking if empty array is array?..

Comment: @VaoTsun I suppose counting dimensions again (function doesn't hold it in variable) and returning them is a bit more time consuming than just returning NULL and someone writing this function figured no one needed to check 0 dimension arrays.

Comment: sorry, I meant smth like https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/utils/adt/arrayfuncs.c#L1635 :)